# Kafka Oracle Target via JDBC Sink connector getting unwanted data in the PK column in JSON format. How to strip?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using debezium connector to pull data from Oracle and JDBC Sink connector to insert into Oracle.
I am seeing more data in the primary column for target. Any idea how to strip the data in primary column ? ideally i shall just see value 2

Oracle_Source:
2

Oracle_Target:
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"double","optional":false,"field":"ID"}],"optional":false,"name":"TEST.Key"},"payload":{"ID":2.0}}

```
{
"name": "TEST",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "table.name.format": "TGT_TEST",
    "topics": "dev.KAFKA.KAFKA_TABLE",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xx:xx/xxx",
    "connection.user": "xxx",
    "connection.password": "xxx",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "delete.enabled": "true",
    "pk.fields": "ID",
    "pk.mode": "record_key",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": true,
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": false
}
```

}

Comment: Please show your sink connector config

Comment: @OneCricketeer - Update with JDBC config

Comment: What happens when you set `"key.converter` to use JSONConverter? The primary key colon is added by the Kafka record key, which you have shown to be JSON... Otherwise, change your producer code to use DoubleSerializer and use DoubleConverter in the sink, not JSON keys.

Comment: @OneCricketeer - getting this error - ConnectException: Sink connector 'Test' is configured with 'delete.enabled=true' and 'pk.mode=record_key' and therefore requires records with a non-null key and non-null Struct or primitive key schema

Comment: Do you need to support deletes as well? If not, you could set `delete.enabled=false`. Otherwise, I haven't used the connector with Oracle, but I dont think this is expected behavior. See https://rmoff.net/2021/03/12/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink-deep-dive-working-with-primary-keys/